# Determine the number of coloring of the circuit $C_7$ with x colors so that no adjacent vertices have identical colors.

Tags: graph-theory

Determine the number of coloring of the circuit $C_7$ with x colors so that no adjacent vertices have identical colors.

I'm quite unsure what it means by circuit of $C_7$ Is it just a septagon?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please read this text about [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question).

Answer (score 0):

$C_7$ is a [cycle graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cycle_graph) with 7 vertices (and so also 7 edges).

So yes, a heptagon.

Comment: Now it is a matter of linguistics whether a heptagon and a septagon are the same :) I am on your side that Greek is the way to go